eprosima::fastcdr::Cdr::DDS_CDR
i am trying to build micro ros agent package on ubuntu 22.04 working on ros2 humble but this error appears  /home/boxtech/ros4_ws/src/micro_ros_agent/micro_ros_agent/src/agent/graph_manager/graph_typesupport.cpp:57:33: error: ‘DDS_CDR’ is not a member of ‘eprosima::fastcdr::Cdr’
57 |         eprosima::fastcdr::Cdr::DDS_CDR);
|

I have just checked that micro-ROS Agent builds in a fresh humble docker, you have my session here:
https://asciinema.org/a/y45zFgRiYwqMca7u9t1yGtshg
So, I cannot replicate your error, could you please provide the steps you are following to get this error?
Ideally, could you do that in a Github Issue in the micro-ROS Agent repository?

good morning i am trying to build my ardupilot package and i am encountering this error  /home/boxtech/rosf_ws/src/micro_ros_agent/micro_ros_agent/src/agent/graph_manager/graph_typesupport.cpp:59:33: error: ‘DDS_CDR’ is not a member of ‘eprosima::fastcdr::Cdr’
59 |         eprosima::fastcdr::Cdr::DDS_CDR);
